# Unable to compile a document containing autoref to figure labels using xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, labels, autoref

When I try to build my document using `xelatex` when `\autoref` tries to reference a figure label

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TEX options = -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %DOC%
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass[corpo=11pt,twoside,tipotesi=magistrale,greek]{toptesi}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9


\begin{figure}
    \caption{A caption.}
    \label{fig:did-arch}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:did-arch}.



\end{document}
```

The error will be

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\figureautorefname ...\texteta \textmu \textalpha 
                                                  
\HyRef@currentHtag ->\figureautorefname 
                                        ~
<argument> \HyRef@currentHtag 
                              \expandafter \@firstoffive \r@fig:did-arch \@e...

\hyper@link #1#2#3->\hyper@linkstart {#1}{#2}#3
                                               \Hy@xspace@end \hyper@linkend 
\HyRef@autosetref ...empty \@empty \@empty \null }
                                                  \else \protect \G@refundef...

\HyRef@autoref ... \csname r@#2\endcsname {#2}{#1}
                                                  \endgroup 
l.58 \autoref{fig:did-arch}
```

Using `pdflatex` will not generate any error however the reference to `fig:did-arch` will be undefined.

EDIT: obviously the reference will fail because a caption was missing. Still getting the same error using `xelatex` though.

Comment: probably unrelated but never use T1 fontenc with xelatex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal document showing the issue is

```
\documentclass[
  corpo=11pt,
  twoside,
  tipotesi=magistrale,
  greek
]{toptesi}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption.}
  \label{fig:did-arch}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:did-arch}.

\end{document}
```

There is no `greek` option to `toptesi`, as far as I know. If the document is processed with `pdflatex`, the option is passed to `babel`, which knows how to cope with it; but with XeLaTeX, `polyglossia` is employed and it *doesn't* really know what to do with the option.

Declare Greek as an “other language” in the proper way.

```
\documentclass[
  corpo=11pt,
  twoside,
  tipotesi=magistrale,
]{toptesi}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setotherlanguage{greek}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption.}
  \label{fig:did-arch}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:did-arch}.

\end{document}
```

*Important footnote*. Don't load `fontenc` and `lmodern` with XeLaTeX.